# How to loop through collection, separating results by identical column values

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a table which has columns for "Week" (integer) and "Lesson name" (string). I am returning the collection and passing it to the view, and want to loop through the collection to group the lessons by week. How do I do this? I think I need to use a for each loop but not sure how to write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `groupBy()` method? in: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

```
$users = DB::table('lessons')
            ->groupBy('week')
            ->having('week', '>', 1)
            ->get(['lesson_name']);
```

> PS: I'm referring to Laravel 5.2 docs because I presently use 5.2

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data looks like this,

```
$data = [
    [
        'week' => 1,
        'lesson' => "A",
    ],
    [
        'week' => 2,
        'lesson' => "B",
    ],
    [
        'week' => 1,
        'lesson' => "C",
    ],
    [
        'week' => 1,
        'lesson' => "D",
    ]
];
```

Then, using collect you can call groupBy function and passing in the parameter(column of the table)

```
$data = collect($data)->groupBy('week');
```